# Switch django cache backend according to URL

Tags: django, caching, memcached

How to use django `per-view` cache which for the same view uses `memcached` for some URLs and `filesystem` cache for others  ?

Comment: Assuming you're using `cache_page` decorator you can pass it a keyword argument `cache` which points to specific cache. For instance if the settings.py cointains CACHES setting with keys "default", "memcached" and "filesystem" you can use cache_page with `cache="memcached"` for some views and "filesystem" for others. Skipping this keyword argument will result in using default cache.

Comment: what if I need to use the same view which means the same cache_page decorator call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Django comes with solution for this problem. You can however create a decorator based on `cache_page`.

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

def smart_cache_page(timeout):
    def outer(view):
        cached_with_memcached = cache_page(timeout, cache="memcached")(view)
        cached_with_filesystem = cache_page(timeout, cache="filesystem")(view)

        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if condition_to_use_memcached:  # build the condition based on request, args and kwargs which will be different per request
                return cached_with_memcached(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return cached_with_filesystem(request, *args, **kwargs)

        return inner

    return outer

@smart_cache_page(60)
def my_view(request):
    # view code
```

Now the decorator will decide which cache to use based on the condition you put into `smart_cache_page` for every request.

Keep in mind each view you decorate this way will use the same logic. If you need more flexibility you can make the condition as an additional parameter to `smart_cache_page` but this can lead to complicated code depending on how many caches you want to use.